# Where to go for [mcedit]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There's a tag for [mcedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcedit). Here's its tag excerpt and wiki:

> mcedit is an editor included with Midnight Commander featuring syntax highlighting for many languages, macros, code snippets, etc.

> `mcedit` is an editor included with [Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org), which can be executed as standalone program or from Midnight Commander using the F4 key.
>
> Features include syntax highlighting for many languages, macros, code snippets, simple integration with external tools, automatic indentation, mouse support, clipboard and the ability to work in both ASCII and hex modes.

**However**,  *another* MCEdit exists. It happens to be a [Minecraft](http://minecraft.net) world editor [`http://www.mcedit.net/`](http://www.mcedit.net/) which enables users to write custom filters in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). It also takes up a good chunk on the first page for a [duckduckgo query of `MCEdit`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=MCEdit):

[image]

And... Here's the problem, most of the questions tagged with [mcedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcedit) are about the Minecraft world editor, not the Midnight Commander editor. For your convenience I've went through the current [mcedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcedit) questions and indicated what they're asking for with a pen to the left. Notice that the ones in boxes references [mcedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcedit) as the Minecraft world editor:

[image]

**I know this isn't going to work out, but only 20% of these questions conveys the tags' original purpose. We have to modify the tag to either:**

1. Include the Minecraft world editor.
2. Change it to reference the Minecraft world editor altogether, and untag it from the two Midnight Commander questions.
3. Burninate it altogether since it's ambiguous and isn't an useful tag.

What does everyone think?

Comment: Freehand should still be RED even if you invert colors!!!

Comment: @nicael http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-red

Comment: I mean you should first invert colors AND then apply RED freehand :D. I know that red is inverted to blue.

Comment: Just brainstorming: Why not keep [tag:mcedit] for Midnight Commander, because it was there first and use a different tag for Minecraft, for example, [tag:mcworldeditor]?

Comment: But the world editor is called MCEdit also @honk, having  [tag:mcworldeditor] doesn't make it clear for question askers to use that instead of [tag:mcedit].

Comment: That's true, because sadly nearly nobody reads the tag descriptions ;) Therefore I expected your argument. However, I think you would be happy to retag all wrong [tag:mcedit] tags :p

Comment: I think that it is a useful tag as it is currently used because mcedit (minecraft) filters are on-topic, and definitely something there could be experts on. Splitting the tag would probably be a good thing... maybe "midnight-commander-editor" and "mcedit-world-editor".

Comment: @kittycat3141 I'm more leaning towards option 2, as mcedit questions already comes with mc, which renders mcedit as a meta tag. However please feel free to make an answer with a possible solution for the community to vote on.

Answer (score 4):

I propose that we change the tag:

[mcedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcedit) as the tag [mc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mc) already exists and is a meta tag for [mc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mc) (Midnight Commander), nor brings convenience for searchers and makes it more accessible.

On the other hand, [mcedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcedit) as a tag for the Minecraft world editor makes the tag more accurate, and as a programmable medium has a better defined scope that is likely to help more users.

---

[mc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mc) [mcedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcedit) questions can be retagged to [mcedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcedit) where appropriate, and [mcedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcedit) can have its description and wiki to be changed to define its usage for the world editor and point to [mc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mc) for Midnight Commander questions.

Of course, that's a drastic change so we should only do that with community consensus.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea because there are so few questions that a split between Midnight Commander and its editor seems dubious.

Answer (score 3):

Splitting the tag might be a good idea, since both uses of it are good tags. We could replace it with something like "midnight-commander-editor" and "mcedit-world-editor".